# Overlay transition position calculation for one image slide effect

Tags: ffmpeg

Someone asked a similar question except that they were sliding many images and therefore couldn't figure out my solution out of their answer. I am trying to slide only one image from right to left by overlaying it on a background image. My starting position(640) is shifted so that the sliding image is not visible at the beginning but the background image. The goal is to have the image start sliding at 46 seconds and stop when it is in the same position as the background image rather than continuing to slide until it disappears. Below is what I have tried without any success.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 67 -i background.png -loop 1 -t 5 image1.png
       -filter_complex
        "[0:v]scale=640x720,setsar=1/1[v0];[1:v]scale=640x720,setsar=1/1[v1]
        [v0][v1]overlay=shortest=1:x='min(640,-(t-46)*100))'"
       -y output.mp4
```

I think it has something to do with (*100) but I just can't come up with the solution. I've exhausted all my tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 67 -i background.png -loop 1 -t 6.5 image1.png 
  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640x720,setsar=1/1[v0];
                   [1:v]scale=640x720,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS+46/TB[v1];
                   [v0][v1]overlay=shortest=1:x='max(0,640-(t-46)*100))':enable='gte(t,46)'"
  -y output.mp4
```